# How to interate over all Postman environment variables?

Tags: request, environment-variables, postman

In one of my pre-request script I need to have my url with all environment variables reaplced. Suddenly the env vars are injected only after the pre-request script. I want to iterate over the env variables and manually replace them. Is it possible?
I can get pm.environment.values, but suddenly this object is not an array. I cant get any values from it with `pm.environment.values[0]` or use a `for(const element of pm.environment.values)` on it.
If I could get all environment keys, i could acomlish my aim with `pm.environment.get`, but I did not found a way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried `pm.environment.toObject()` and then iterate over that?

Comment: @DannyDainton genius. That worked. Create an real answer, i will accept it.

Comment: for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(pm.environment.toObject())) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.toObject()` function. It returns all variables with their values, in the active environment, in a single object:

```js
pm.environment.toObject()
```

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-environment-variables-in-scripts

This will also work for other variable scopes such as Collection, Iteration and Global.